# SQL Server 2008 trigger to modify file

Tags: file, sql-server-2008, triggers

I need help please about SQL Server 2008 and triggers.

The context: a machine has generated data (number: integer) that I need to inject into a xml file. This data changes a few times a day, but I need it in real time.

**Problem**: the data is not available directly from the machine, no way... but this machine feeds a SQL Server 2008 database.

So, I think a better way is using a SQL Server trigger. Am I wrong ?

Here's code I'm using:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Test]  
ON [dbo].[Table_machine]  
AFTER UPDATE   
AS  
    IF UPDATE(Valeur) 
    BEGIN
        **********************************
    END
```

This trigger works on 'Valeur' update but I don't know how to modify my xml file?

Answer (score 1):

I would **strongly recommend AGAINST** putting such logic that does a lot of conversion and writes out to a file system into a trigger - it will slow down the normal operation of the database quite significantly. And triggers and T-SQL are severely limited in what they can do in the file system.

My approach would be:

- create a separate application/tool, e.g. in C# or whatever other language you know, and handle the logic of creating that XML from the database and storing it into a file in there
- have that tool scheduled by e.g. Windows Scheduler or some other mechanism to be run on a regular basis - whether that's every 10 minutes, or every hour is up to you to decide

The **main benefits** are:

- you've *not* severely slowed down your database operation
- you have more programming power at your disposal to write that logic
- you can schedule it to run as frequently or as infrequently as needed (e.g. every 5 minutes during working weekdays from 6am to 10pm - and only once an hour outside these hours - or whatever you choose to do)

Comment: Thanks for reply ! It's a good idea and I will try this solution to compare difference with my new solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply !
It's a good idea and I will try this solution to compare difference with my new solution.

I've tried with trigger EXEC xp_cmdshell 'D:\MyApp.exe'
I create MyApp.exe application who do all modifications in my xml file. 
It works perfectly except to send modified data in sql database. I don't know how to take this value...
It must be EXEC xp_cmdshell 'D:\MyApp.exe Valeur' but I don't know how to grab 'Valeur'.

With this solution, database must NOT be too slow, no ? Because Trigger only launch a shell command ?
The only one value I need in database could change 20 times per minute or only 2 times per day but I need this value in 'real time'. So scheduler would not be accurate enough...